# Spark incorrectly interpret partition name ending with 'd' or 'f' as number when reading partitioned parquets

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using `spark.read.parquet()` to read from a folder where parquet files are organized in partitions. The result will be wrong when the partition name ends with `f` or `d`. Apparently, Spark will interpret them as number instead of string. I have created a minimal test case as below to reproduce the problem.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
            ('9q', 1),
            ('3k', 2),
            ('6f', 3),
            ('7f', 4),
            ('7d', 5),
     ],
     schema='foo string, id integer'
)
df.write.partitionBy('foo').parquet('./tmp_parquet', mode='overwrite')
read_back_df = spark.read.parquet('./tmp_parquet')
read_back_df.show()
```

The `read_back_df` will be

```
+---+---+                                                                       
| id|foo|
+---+---+
|  1| 9q|
|  4|7.0|
|  3|6.0|
|  2| 3k|
|  5|7.0|
+---+---+
```

Notice partition `6f/7f/7d` becomes `6.0/7.0/7.0`.

The spark version is 2.4.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behaviour that you see is expected.

From the [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery):

> Notice that the data types of the partitioning columns are automatically inferred.

You can disable this feature by setting `spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled` to False.

The following code preserves the strings when reading the parquet file:

```python
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled", False)
read_back_df = spark.read.parquet('./tmp_parquet')
read_back_df.show()
```

prints

```
+---+---+                                                                       
| id|foo|
+---+---+
|  3| 6f|
|  1| 9q|
|  4| 7f|
|  2| 3k|
|  5| 7d|
+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The change of the said setting indeed works. However, I feel like there is still a question left unawered. How come values like 6f or 7f is inferred as float? Isn't that strange?

Comment: Have a look at [this code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/bc1acfeaab93998df61af8319df85cc949d8f0d0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/PartitioningUtils.scala#L478). Spark simply takes the name of the folder and tries to parse the name. 6f is a valid expression for a float.